# Visual Studio, how to get files to show in Listbox Powershell

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, listbox

I have created a PowerShell GUI that combines 2 pdf documents, then converts it to a `.tif`, then renames it and finally moves it to its final location.

I would like to use a ListBox to show the actions of the above scripts if this is possible

So in the first ListBox it needs to show the 2 pdf files that are going to be combined.

I cant seem to get it to show any file!

```
$listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged = {
    $listBox1.Text = Get-ChildItem "E:\SIGNEDNOTES" -Filter *.pdf
}
```

```
$listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged = {

    $rootFolder = "E:\SIGNEDNOTES\" 
    $subfolders = (Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Filter *.pdf -Recurse -Directory).FullName
    $listBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
    $listBox1.Items.AddRange($subfolders)

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Assuming this is windows forms, you'll need to add each item to `$listBox1.Items`

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes it is a windows form. do you have an example please

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i have edited my question am i along the right tracks?

Comment: I haven't much done the form-based Powershell C# myself but I think you need to cast the results in $subfolders as an object without a heading in C# so it knows how to interpret it.  Something like `ListBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[]{$subfolders}` and I thought in C# we needed to use `this.Listbox1.` to reference the object, but again I really only dabbled in this, so that might be optional or just an artifact from learning it on the fly not needed)

Comment: thank you for your comment @BenPersonick i am in the same boat i had code working but now it wont show anything in the listbox so annoying haha

Comment: You don't need to new up the  listbox again, that's why your list is empty!  `$listBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox1`.  Delete that line.  That line is only creating a new list in PowerShell memory and not placing it on your form at all.  Instead, you just need to add items to the list, nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add new items to a `ListBox` you need to populate the `ListBox.Items` collection.  Here's a quick example.

Given this XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="138" Margin="84,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="332"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm assuming you've already got a method to use a XAML layout in PowerShell, but if you don't, you can use the method I cover in this blog post '[Using GUI Elements in PowerShell](https://foxdeploy.com/2015/05/14/part-iii-using-advanced-gui-elements-in-powershell/)'.

My `listBox` is called `$WPFlistBox`, so here's how I would populate that.

```
$items = get-childItem c:\temp\*.exe 
ForEach($item in $items){
   $WPFlistBox.Items.Add($item.FullName)
}
```

Just change the variables to match your own and you should be well on your way.

Here's an example of what it looks like.
[image]

Comment: You need to trigger the logic to populate your list, right now you have that logic within this event handler. `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged `.  Are you invoking that?  Just to be sure, try moving your list population logic outside of an event handler so that it runs by defaulkt

Comment: thank you for your help that's great, @FoxDeploy could you do another one of you great examples please just so i can nail this. thanks again

Comment: Happy it helps.  What are you asking for precisely?  You can have anything you want, so long as it isn't another blog post in that series . They took soo much work and time...